# download attendance and user infos from zkteco device and insert them into odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I installed zklib ( via Pip :ubuntu machine https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zklib) to download attendance and user infos from zkteco device and insert them into odoo.

as a first step I tried to connect:

```html
import sys
import zklib
import time
from zklib import zkconst
zk = zklib.ZKLib("192.168.1.201", 4370)
ret = zk.connect()
print "connection:", ret
```

My issue is that I'm getting connection false, even I can ping `192.168.1.201`
and sure that 4370 is the right port

Comment: Did you check whether a comm key was set for the device in question? If yes, it won't authenticate the connection request. And I myself haven't figured out how to pass that into  the ZK connect call either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what device you are using. However, recent implementation of pyzk library by fananimi is a great place to start. It gives you ability to let you use password. It has implementation for both UDP and TCP enabled devices.

Answer (score 0):

it is a device model question, `zklib` doesn't work with all devices